NextJS 14 SSR - adding to a list client side after initial render
Im new to NextJS 14 and would kindly ask anybody who would know how to add to a list after fetching from a server component. Basically I wish to add additional items to the current list. Already I have a client component that has "use client" and has the props parsed down from the server component which calls from mongo db. But I have no idea what best practice is to update the list on the client component. I have tried the following using the props and a seperate state using setState. Although it works, to me it looks like a hack. (jobs is the initial data parsed prop from the server.) I wish to keep the initial render for SEO reasons and speed)
// server comp

  const jobResults = await getPagedJobsData(query) 

  return (
      <HomePage data={jobResults}/>
  )
 }



// HomePage client component

 const Home = ({data}) => {

  const {jobs} = data

  //const jobs = []

  const [initialRender, setInitialRender] = useState(false)
  const [jobData, setJobData] = useState(null)
  const didMount = useRef(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  useEffect(()=> {
    setInitialRender(true)
    setJobData(jobs)
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    // Return early, if this is the first render:
    if ( ! didMount.current ) {
     return ()=> didMount.current = true;
    }

    // Paste code to be executed on subsequent renders:
    let query = {
      page_num: count,
      title: '',
      location : '',
      contractTypeSel : '',
      remoteDays : "Any",
      skills: ''
    }

    const prepare = async () => {
      let t = await getPagedJobsData(query)
      const addtionalJobs =  t.jobs
      setJobData([...jobData, ...addtionalJobs])

    }

    prepare()


  }, [count]);


  const handlePageClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }


  return  (
    <>
    <div className='border'>
      <div>
        <div className=''>
          { 
            initialRender == false ? jobs.map((item, index)=> {
              return <div key={index}>{item.company}</div>
            })
            : jobData.map((item, index)=> {
              return <div key={index}>{item.company}</div>
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div> 
    <div className=' items-center'>
          <button onClick={handlePageClick}>More</button>
    </div> 
   </>
 





There's a few issues here.
First, you don't need the useEffect hook to set the state with the data you passed in. You can change that to this:
const Home = ({data}) => {

  const {jobs} = data

  //const jobs = []

  const [initialRender, setInitialRender] = useState(false)
  const [jobData, setJobData] = useState(jobs) // Just insert them as the initial state here.
  const didMount = useRef(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  useEffect(()=> {
    setInitialRender(true)
  }, [])

And second, you most likely want to move that second useEffect hook and the async function into a server component and just move the button to a client component. One of the big changes that Next 13+ kind of forces developers to get used to is the fact that you'll likely have several really small components, just so they can be rendered on the client while the majority is rendered on the server.
Instead of using state to store the page data, use searchParams which will be automatically passed into the page component, and then change the onClick method to an href and use a Next.js Link component. If you do that, you don't even need the client component mentioned above at all. All in all, that would end up looking like this:
const Home = ({searchParams: {
    page,
    // showAll - Look below. Whichever works best with what you're trying to accomplish.
}})

 let query = {
      page_num: count, // Apply some logic here to use the page or showAll param.
      title: '',
      location : '',
      contractTypeSel : '',
      remoteDays : "Any",
      skills: ''
    }

      const jobs = await getPagedJobsData(query)

  return (
      <HomePage data={jobResults}/>
  )
 }



// HomePage client component -- Make this a server component now!

 const Home = ({data}) => {

  const {jobs} = data

  return  (
    <>
    <div className='border'>
      <div>
        <div className=''>
          { 
            initialRender == false ? jobs.map((item, index)=> {
              return <div key={index}>{item.company}</div>
            })
            : jobData.map((item, index)=> {
              return <div key={index}>{item.company}</div>
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div> 
    <div className='items-center'>
          <Link
            href={`/somePage?page=${currentPage + 1}`}
            // href={`/somePage?showAll=true`} Whichever fits your use case.
        >More</Link>
    </div> 
   </>
 )}

Extending the initial list using only css.
const itemsToShow = 20
const MyList = async () => {
   const items = await getItems(count: 50)
   return (
<div id="someId" className="group/listContainer">{items.map((item, idx) => <div className={idx >= itemsToShow ? "hidden group-[.expanded]/listContainer:flex" : "flex"}>{item.name}</div>)}</div>
<div onClick={() => document.getItemById(someId).classList.toggle("expanded")}>More</div>
)
}

These css classes assume you're using tailwind, but you can just as easily accomplish the same thing with just 10-20 lines of regular css.

Hi Andrew. Thank you so much for your response. I made good progress with your solution. I have replicated your solution moving everything as a server component. It works on a page-by-page basis. However, I wish to add to the existing list after clicking 'More'. How would I go about doing that at a server level? I can only think of changing getPagedJobsData..but that could be costly from a Mongo db point of view.

If I understand what you're asking correctly, keep everything a server component, except for one tiny client component, a button to toggle the 'more' state. Instead of keeping that in state, have that completely rely on css. You can then return more than what you're displaying originally in the first call to Mongo, and then just apply a css class or a data attribute somewhere with that 1 tiny client component, and all server components can respond to that without any issue.

Hi Andrew...thanks for your reply. So adding to the existing list would be done using CSS only? So I'll be adding to the DOM? Is it possible for you to share a code snippet?

I just edited the answer to include a snippet above.
